Why does my python program start another instance of itself at a button click?
Every time I click a button in the app I am currently working on, the program goes to "no response" and then launches another instance of itself while the old one is still active. I don't know how or why because while having it run inside the IDE it works. As soon as I pack it with auto-py-to-exe, it does this.
The code for the Button:
info_but = customtkinter.CTkButton(menu,text="", font=custom_font,          
                                image=info_def,bg_color="#FDF6E4",fg_color="#FDF6E4",hover_color="#3b444b",
                                width=70, command= info_menu,height=70)
info_but.place(x=20, y=220)


The function getting called:
def info_menu():
    global update_label, gpu_label

    stop_thread()
    # Beispielverwendung
    os_ver = f"{uname().system} {uname().release}"  # get_gpu_models()

    threaded_check_for_new_version(repo_owner, repo_name, current_version)

    proc_info = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()

    # RAM Informationen

    ram = psutil.virtual_memory()

    for child in frame.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()

    content_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(frame, width=880, height=600)
    content_frame.place(x=0, y=0)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"General Information:",anchor="w", justify="left", width=200, height=30, font=custom_font2)
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10,10),pady=(10,30))

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"App version:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"{current_version}",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Build date:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"05/2024",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Publisher:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Update avaiable:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    update_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Working"
                                   ,anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    update_label.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Authentic:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Yes",anchor="w", width=130, height=30,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)


    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"System Information:",anchor="w", justify="left", width=200, height=30, font=custom_font2)
    label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=(10,10),pady=(20,10))


    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"CPU Model:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)


    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"{'{0}'.format(proc_info['brand_raw'])}",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font,wraplength=130)
    label.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Architecture:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"{'{0}'.format(proc_info['arch'])}",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)


    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"OS:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"{os_ver}",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"GPU:",anchor="w", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=11, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    gpu_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Working",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    gpu_label.grid(row=11, column=1, padx=360,pady=10)


    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Avaiable RAM:",anchor="nw", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=12, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"{str(ram.total / 1024**3)[:4]} GB",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=12, column=1, padx=360,pady=(10,10))

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"",anchor="nw", width=130, justify="left", height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=13, column=0, padx=(150,10),pady=10)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"",anchor="w", width=130, height=20,font=custom_font)
    label.grid(row=13, column=1, padx=360,pady=(10,10))

    threaded_get_gpu_models(gpu_label)

affecting:
def fetch_latest_version(repo_owner, repo_name, current_version):
    global cached_result
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/releases/latest"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        latest_version = response.json().get('tag_name')
        comparison_result = semver.compare(current_version, latest_version)
        if comparison_result < 0:
            cached_result = [True, latest_version]
        elif comparison_result == 0:
            cached_result = [False, latest_version]
        else:
            cached_result = [False, current_version]  # Deine Version ist neuer
    else:
        cached_result = [False, None]

    update_label_text()


def update_label_text():
    global cached_result, update_label
    if cached_result[0]:
        update_label.configure(text="Yes")
    else:
        if cached_result[1] is None:
            update_label.configure(text="Error")
        else:
            update_label.configure(text="No")
    root.update()


def check_for_new_version(repo_owner, repo_name, current_version):
    global cached_result, cache_lock
    root.update()
    with cache_lock:
        if cached_result[1] is None:
            fetch_latest_version(repo_owner, repo_name, current_version)
        else:
            update_label_text()


def threaded_check_for_new_version(repo_owner, repo_name, current_version):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=check_for_new_version, args=(repo_owner, repo_name, current_version))
    thread.start()


def fetch_gpu_models(result):
    try:
        gpus = GPUtil.getGPUs()
        gpu_models = set(gpu.name for gpu in gpus)
        result.append(list(gpu_models) if gpu_models else ["Unknown"])
    except Exception as e:
        result.append(["Unknown"])
    update_model_label(gpu_label,result[0])


def update_model_label(gpu_label,gpu_models):
    gpu_label.configure(text=f"{gpu_models[0]}")
    root.update()


def get_gpu_models(gpu_label):
    result = []
    fetch_gpu_models(result)
    return result[0] if result else ["Unknown"]


def threaded_get_gpu_models(gpu_label):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=get_gpu_models, args=(gpu_label,))
    thread.start()

I fixed all errors the IDE threw at me when I clicked the button like thread handling and such, but still no luck. I also changed the names of the variable and function because I noticed that I (stupid) used the name multiple times for different things..
stop_thread is NOT the culprit since it was added AFTER the error occured.

What is info_menu?

Info_menu is the function getting called upon the button click. It contains a lot of label definitions like content and coordinates. It also contains the function calls shown in the second code block :)

And you didn't think that might be relevant to answering your question?

I thought that the information that the info_menu just contains label placements is enough since I am quite confident that those are not at fault :( . I think that the problem must be at the functions in block 2 or 3 . This is the only "active" stuff happening in info_menu. I will try to add the function as an answer

I think you need to call multiprocessing.freeze_support() (need to import multiprocessing module).
